# How can I make a border with CSS around some elements without specifing an absolute width?

Tags: html, css, border

I am new to CSS and would like to draw a border around this:

```css
fieldset {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}

legend {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left-width;
  50%;
  color: #0667ad;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.menu {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 271px;
}

p {
  margin: 1px;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  background-color: #84b0d4;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 8em;
}

input {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<form name="SomeForm" method="post" action="SomeAction">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>
    <div class="menu">
      <p><label for="UserName">Username</label><input name="UserName" id="UserName" type="text" value="#data[1].username#"></p>
      <p><label for="Password">Password</label><input name="Password" id="Password" type="password" value="#data[1].password#"></p>
      <p><label for="FirstName">First name</label><input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" value="#data[1].firstname#"></p>
      <p><label for="LastName">Last name</label><input name="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" value="#data[1].lastname#"></p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Right now I have defined the div width as `271px`. Is there a way to wrap the border around the elements it contains without specifing an absolute width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left` from your labels, add `float: left` to your div.menu, and remove the `width: 271px` from your div.menu.

The reason it breaks now when you remove the width from div.menu is because the labels are floated left and not clearing the input above them.

**Edit:**
Another option if you want to leave the labels floated left would be to add a clearing rule to the paragraphs within the menu:

```
div.menu p { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
div.menu {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

and

```
<div class="menu">
  <p><label for="UserName">Username</label><input name="UserName" id="UserName" type="text" value="#data[1].username#"></p>
  <p><label for="Password">Password</label><input name="Password" id="Password" type="password" value="#data[1].password#"></p>
  <p><label for="FirstName">First name</label><input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" value="#data[1].firstname#"></p>
  <p><label for="LastName">Last name</label><input name="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" value="#data[1].lastname#"></p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: float: left is enough.
what does the second div do?

Comment: this works for me **only** when i take the `float:left` off of `label`.

Comment: @mrt181: when an element is left-floated, it doesn't occupy any space in its container. therefore, the menu div could break out of your fieldset, pretty much depending on what the rest of the page looks like. i just realized i placed it inside the div in error, though, it should clear it just after it instead. editing...

Comment: @David It would be nice if you explained the "clear fix" instead of just dumping a snippet on here.

Comment: The clear fix can usually also be avoided by setting overflow: auto on the parent element.

Comment: @Josh: i agree about that, but at least now it's explained in the comments